# how import a mysqldump without ENGINE specified in MyISAM

Tags: mysql, myisam, mysqlimport

all my sqldumps are without the "Engine=..." syntax in the CREATE Statements, so
maybe i can somehow add "ENGINE=MyISAM" to the default import?

because on my ubuntu 12.04 server with mysql 5.5 importing a large table is very slow, because it is using the standard InnoDB when i just import it

or can i set a settings flag in mysql, that new tables created are MyIsam as default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set the default engine to MyISAM, use the following configuration option in `my.cnf`:

```
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-engine-setting.html), you can:

1. start the server with a specified default storage engine:

   > You can specify the default engine by using the --default-storage-engine server startup option,
2. change the config file

   > or by setting the default-storage-engine option in the my.cnf configuration file.
3. change the engine on a session by session basis

   > You can set the default storage engine to be used during the current session by setting the default_storage_engine variable